# complete metric space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Prove or disprove:  $(A_i)_{i=1}^\infty$ are closed subsets in a complete metric space. Assume that there is an open ball in the $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^\infty A_i$ , so exists $k$  s.t  $A_k$ contains an open ball as well.

Thank you!

Comment: Please elucidate: What did you try, what are your thoughts, where are you stuck?

Comment: is it a homework?

Comment: it is homework, I couldn't find any example to disprove that but I have no clue how to start the proof, if it is true, so I will be glad to get a hint or direction...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Hint:** [Baire category theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_category_theorem). If no $A_k$ contains an open ball, then all $A_k$'s are nowhere dense, hence $\bigcup_{k} A_k$ ...